# TFS Shell Integration - TF Power Tools requires Visual Studio 2010

Tags: tfs, shell-extensions, tfs-power-tools

I just started using Team Foundation 2010, but I'm connecting to the server with Visual Studio 2008 SP1. It's working alright, except I can't install Power Tools to include shell integration because for some reason it requires Visual Studio 2010.

1) Is there any way I can get tfpt Shell Integration without having to install VS2010 ?

Second question is... I installed VS2010 in one machine and used the power tools for awhile. But when I changed the server IP, shell extension suddenly stopped working... It tries to reconnect and fails. I tried executing this, with no success:

tf.exe workspaces /remove:*

But I don't know if it has anything to do with my problem.

2) What happened to the shell integration? how can i solve it ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try installing the TFS2008 (October) power tools instead of the TFS 2010 ones?  Not sure if that will work, but that's where I would start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the shell extensions you need to have [team explorer 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=fe4f9904-0480-4c9d-a264-02fedd78ab38&displaylang=en) running on your machine. Install team explorer 2010 and then the power tools and you are ready to go.

When you are not able to connect to the tfs server, the removal of the workspaces will also not happen. That action needs a connection to the TFS server. Has your password been changed lately? If so, you might need to update the stored windows credential (available through the control panel). To investigate the connection problems, you could navigate to TWA (http://myserverip:8080/tfs/web)

Comment: Thanks for the response. My password hasn't changed, but the server ip has. I'm able to navigate to the web access, and connect in visual studio, but when in windows explorer it acts like there's no connection, and when I click to reconnect, it fails. Any clues?